# Puppet Facter MAC to determine model

Tags: macos, puppet, facter

I'm trying to set up a Puppet module with an if statement and Facter.
Something like:

```
if $something-factor = macpro
    do THIS

elsif $something factor = macair
    do THIS
```

I just can't seem to find the Facter variable to do this.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few facts that you might try using for this, depending how specific you need to be about the model information.

```
$ facter | grep -i air
productname => MacBookAir5,2
sp_machine_model => MacBookAir5,2
sp_machine_name => MacBook Air
```

Comment: Isn't there a built in puppet facter variable that can do it?

Comment: I think I got it: sp_machine_model